# Steps to find the current firmware verison of Mercedes Command

Tags: mercedes-benz, navigation, center-console

I want to know what firmware is currently running on my '14 E350 Mercedes Command and Navigation.

How and where to navigate to get that information?
Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted to find this information so far?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm taking the vehicle delivery today or tomorrow at the least, I wanted to ask the question, if I don't get any answer, answer it myself, by looking into the settings, and hopefully something related to "About" from the infotainment.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Maps screen, exit fullscreen, click on Nav> scroll to the very end> Map version.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzj_F7fR53q6b0NXWWx5UGlZMXc

But, I still don't know the Command version..! I have to do more research.